# Event handler not invoked when event is fired

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

I am having trouble raising event from one component and capturing it in another component.

Here is what i am trying to do.

- I have button on my home page.
  [image]
- Clicking the button opens the first modal dialog which has another button to open a second modal dialog
  [image]
  **Problem:**

Clicking the button "Open Another modal" is supposed to fire an event on another component and open the second modal dialog, but that does not happen.

Here is the code.

**Application**

```
<aura:application >
<ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS052017/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css" />
<c:ModalDialog1 />  
<c:ModalDialog2 />
```

**ModalDialog1.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
<!--use boolean attribute for Store true/false value,
make default to "false" so modal box are not display on the load of component. 
--> 
<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>


<!--Use "slds-m-around- -xx-large" class to add standard Large padding to the component--> 
<div class="slds-m-around--xx-large">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.openModel}">Open Modal Dialog</button>  

    <!--Use aura:if tag to display Model Box, on the bese of conditions. [isOpen boolean attribute] -->   
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

        <!--###### MODAL BOX Start From Here ######--> 
        <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header99" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
            <div class="slds-modal__container">
                <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Part Start From Here ######-->
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 id="header99" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Modal Dialog 1</h2>
                </div>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start From Here ######-->
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                    <p><b>This is Modal Dialog 1</b></p>
                </div>
                <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start From Here ######-->
                <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.closeModel}" >Cancel</button>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.openSecondModal}">Open Another Modal</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
        <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

    </aura:if>
</div>
```

**ModelDialog1Controller**

```
({
openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
    component.set("v.isOpen", true);
},

closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
    // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "Fasle"  
    component.set("v.isOpen", false);
},

openSecondModal: function(component, event, helper) {
    // Display alert message on the click on the "Like and Close" button from Model Footer 
    // and set set the "isOpen" attribute to "False for close the model Box.
    component.set("v.isOpen", false);
    var cmpEvent = $A.get('e.c:NavigateEvent');
    cmpEvent.fire();       
    console.log("Event fired.")
},
```

})

**ModelDialog2.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable">
<!--use boolean attribute for Store true/false value,
make default to "false" so modal box are not display on the load of component. 
--> 
<aura:attribute name="isOpen" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:registerEvent name="NavigateEvent" type="c:NavigateEvent"/>
<aura:handler name="NavigateEvent" event="c:NavigateEvent" action="{!c.openModel}"/>

<!--Use aura:if tag to display Model Box, on the bese of conditions. [isOpen boolean attribute] -->   
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isOpen}">

    <!--###### MODAL BOX Start From Here ######--> 
    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header99" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open ">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <!-- ###### MODAL BOX HEADER Part Start From Here ######-->
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h2 id="header99" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Modal Dialog 2</h2>
            </div>
            <!--###### MODAL BOX BODY Part Start From Here ######-->
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <p><b>This is Modal Dialog 2</b></p>
            </div>
            <!--###### MODAL BOX FOOTER Part Start From Here ######-->
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.closeModel}">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>
    <!--###### MODAL BOX Part END Here ######-->

</aura:if>
```

**ModelDialog2Controller**

```
    ({
   openModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Display Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "true"
      // 
      console.log("Open Model 2 called");
      component.set("v.isOpen", true);
   },

   closeModel: function(component, event, helper) {
      // for Hide/Close Model,set the "isOpen" attribute to "Fasle"  
      component.set("v.isOpen", false);
   }
})
```

**Event**

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have registered the event on the **handling** modal, not the **despatching** modal.

Move this from the `ModelDialog2.cmp`:

```
<aura:registerEvent name="NavigateEvent" type="c:NavigateEvent"/>
```

To the `ModalDialog1.cmp` component and I think it should all work.

Your handler is also setup for handling a **COMPONENT** event, not an application event.

Change your handler to this:

```
<aura:handler event="c:NavigateEvent" action="{!c.openModel}"/>
```

Comment: did not help. I guess the problem is in the way i am firing the the event. I can see "Event Fired" in the log. But the log in event handler never gets printed.

Comment: Realised you have another issue with your handler - see edits to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. This issue was with the handler. The event registration is not a problem. It needs to be on the second Modal. Please edit your answer to reflect that so i can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Is this still the case? An event registration informs the framework that you are able to despatch an event - it looks like cmp1 is the despatcher.

Comment: Glad to help either way :)